# Generate a custom object and apply custom fxml file in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I want to program a "Simple UML Editor"

> ## Use Case
>
> Click UML canvas, and generate a UML shape.
>   Cursor is at the UML shape's top left after generated. As [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de0V5.jpg).

---

Here is sample code.

## Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainView.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

## mainView.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<Pane fx:id="canvas" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onMouseClicked="#onMouseClicked" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainViewController" />
```

## MainViewController.java

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class MainViewController {

    @FXML Pane canvas;

    @FXML private void onMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        myCircle c = new myCircle();

        c.setLayoutX(event.getX());
        c.setLayoutY(event.getY());
        canvas.getChildren().add(c);
    }
}
```

## myCircle.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.Scene?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Circle fx:id="circle" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" radius="20.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

## myCircle.java

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.Parent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class myCircle extends Parent {

    @FXML Circle circle;

    public myCircle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myCircle.fxml"));
        //fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.getChildren().add(circle);

        System.out.println("generate myCircle");
    }
}
```

---

## Questions

1. In file: myCircle.java. I can't add code `fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);`, or it will show the error message: "Root value already specified."
   Is the root node dynamic loading? (I didn't use `<fx:root>` or `setRoot()`) If it is dynamic loading, which one is my current root node?
2. In file: myCircle.java. I must add line `this.getChildren().add(circle);`, or there is no circle generate. Why? I think there is some important detail I don't know...
3. I need `centerXProperty()` to implement binding line relative feature, but there is some problem. My custom UML shape apply and load custom fxml file, I couldn't get real centerXProperty. I print centerXProperty messege: `DoubleProperty [bean: Circle[id=circle, centerX=0.0, centerY=0.0, radius=20.0, fill=0x1e90ffff, stroke=0x000000ff, strokeWidth=1.0], name: centerX, value: 0.0]`. The value always is 0.0 no matter what. How could I do?

   ---

I don't want to type spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

1. The root element of your FXML file is a `<Pane>` element, which is basically an instruction to the `FXMLLoader` to create a `Pane` instance, which becomes the root. Thus when you try to call `fxmlLoader.setRoot(...)` it complains, because there is already a root specified in the FXML file. To fix this, you need to use `<fx:root...>` as the root element:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
   <?import java.lang.*?>
   <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
   <?import javafx.scene.Scene?>

   <fx:root type="Pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
       minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
       prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="40.0" 
       xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
      <children>
         <Circle fx:id="circle" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" radius="20.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
      </children>
   </fx:root>
   ```

   In order for `fxmlLoader.setRoot(this)` to work, `this` must be an instance of the class specified by the `type` attribute to `<fx:root>`, i.e. you must make `myCircle` a subclass of `Pane`:

   ```
   package application;

   import java.io.IOException;

   import javafx.fxml.FXML;
   import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
   import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
   import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

   public class myCircle extends Pane {

       @FXML Circle circle;

       public myCircle() {
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
           FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myCircle.fxml"));
           fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
           fxmlLoader.setController(this);
           try {
               fxmlLoader.load();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           // circle is now added to this by the FXML. 
           // So next line is no longer needed:
           // this.getChildren().add(circle);

           System.out.println("generate myCircle");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Is fixed by fixing `fxmlLoader.setRoot(this)`. The circle is a child of the `Pane` that is the root of the FMXL file. Previously, it wasn't added to the `myCircle` instance unless you did so explicitly.
3. You never change the `centerX` and `centerY` properties, so they will always be 0. Did you mean to use `centerX="20"` instead of `layoutX="20"` in the FXML? If you want to expose them for binding/setting/etc you can do so in your `myCircle` class:

   ```
   package application;

   import java.io.IOException;

   import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty ;
   import javafx.fxml.FXML;
   import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
   import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
   import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

   public class myCircle extends Pane {

       @FXML Circle circle;

       public myCircle() {
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
           FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myCircle.fxml"));
           fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
           fxmlLoader.setController(this);
           try {
               fxmlLoader.load();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           // circle is now added to this by the FXML. 
           // So next line is no longer needed:
           // this.getChildren().add(circle);

           System.out.println("generate myCircle");
       }

       public DoubleProperty centerXProperty() {
           return circle.centerXProperty();
       }

       public final double getCenterX() {
           return centerXProperty().get();
       }

       public final void setCenterX(double centerX) {
           centerXProperty().set(centerX);
       }

       // same for centerY...
   }
   ```

   You could also consider just making `MyCircle` a subclass of `Circle`, so that you simply inherit the `centerX` and `centerY` properties. i.e.

   ```
   package application;

   import java.io.IOException;

   import javafx.fxml.FXML;
   import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
   import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

   public class myCircle extends Circle {

       public myCircle() {
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
           FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myCircle.fxml"));
           fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
           fxmlLoader.setController(this);
           try {
               fxmlLoader.load();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           System.out.println("generate myCircle");
       }
   }
   ```

   and then

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
   <?import java.lang.*?>
   <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
   <?import javafx.scene.Scene?>

   <fx:root type="Circle" fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" 
       radius="20.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE"
       xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   </fx:root>
   ```

   though I'm not sure if this still gives you all the functionality you want.